# SQL - All data before current month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to retrieve all data before the current month of today.
for both

MS SQL Server and MySQL

Comment: What does "for both SQL and MySQL" mean? SQL is a _language_ supported by dozens of products, of which MySQL is one.

Comment: However, when it comes to date/time, many SQL products have their own functions instead of the ANSI/ISO SQL standard's. E.g. dateadd and datediff are product specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer for Microsoft SQL Server

```
WHERE DATE <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for? Dateadd, datediff and getdate are all product specific functions.

Comment: edited for clarity

Answer (score 1):

You could try (adapt the syntax according to the particular SQL product you are using):

```
WHERE DATE < DATE_TRUNC('month',getdate())
```